# Singepage Application with Cookie Auth development

Tags: single-page-application, session-cookies

I would like to develop a single page website in Flutter. I have a backend that authenticates users via a session cookie. For development, the website starts under "localhost:port" as with other frameworks like Angular, but the browser (Chrome in debug mode) recognizes that the cookie comes from the domain of my backend and therefore the cookie is no longer valid for "localhost". Is there somehow a workaround how I can use a backend with cookie under another domain during the development of a SPA? Thanks a lot!